# How call a function sequentially in a for loop with setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

I want to execute function in for loop sequentially.

I use node.js, and my code is...

```
var insertData = [];
var interval = 500;

function working1(nodeID, keyword, cb){
    insertData.push(nodeID);
    console.log('working: '+nodeID);
    // get data and add value to insertData 
}

function working2()
{
  // insert insertData to database
}

function getDeviceValue(nodeID){
    insertData.push(nodeID);
    console.log('getDeviceValue : '+nodeID);
    async.series([
            function(calllback){
                   working1(nodeID, 'A', function(data, err){
                           if (err) console.log(err);
                           else calllback(null, data);
                           });
            },
            function(calllback){
                   working1(nodeID, 'B', function(data, err){
                            if (err) console.log(err);
                            else calllback(null, data);
                            });
            },
    ], function(err, results){
          working2();
    });
}

setInterval(function() { // This should work periodically.
    dbData = [];
    for (var i=1; i<=4; i++)
        getDeviceValue('0000'+i);
}, interval);
```

when I was execute above code, it working like...

```
getDeviceValue : 00001
getDeviceValue : 00002
getDeviceValue : 00003
getDeviceValue : 00004
working : 00001
working : 00002
working : 00003
working : 00004
```

but I want to make it work like...

```
getDeviceValue : 00001
working : 00001
getDeviceValue : 00002
working : 00002
getDeviceValue : 00003
working : 00003
getDeviceValue : 00004
working : 00004
```

when I search it, answer is 'use promise'.

How can I use it?

or

Is there any other way?

Comment: One problem is that your `console.log(working: '+nodeID);` is invalid Javascript syntax, so your script shouldn't even run in the first place. Try copying the script itself and pasting it here instead.

Comment: If we fix the obvious errors (not declaring `interval`, the missing quote on the `console.log`), the code above **doesn't** produce the output you say it does.

Comment: I think, this is not full code? @Kown you need to post actual code, producing the issue

Comment: ok i edit code, and it almost full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution without promise, using simple javascript.

```js
var i = 1;
var interval = 500;
var insertData = [];

function working(nodeID){
    insertData.push(nodeID);
    console.log('working: '+nodeID);
}
function getDeviceValue(nodeID){
    insertData.push(nodeID);
    console.log('getDeviceValue : '+nodeID);
    working(nodeID);// Changed
}

function asyncLoop(index) 
{
    if(index > 4) return;
       setTimeout(function() {

       getDeviceValue('0000'+index);
       index++;
       asyncLoop(index);
    }, interval);
}



asyncLoop(i);
```

Comment: You have changed the question. Do you need solution for updated one?

Comment: I edit your answer.    1. Add `setInterval` for `asyncLoop`,    2. `setTimeout` in `asyncLoop` change to `setInterval` and stop using `clearInterval`.  Is it okay to do this?

Comment: @Kown, Yes its ok.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the first `console.log` inside `async.series` as:

```
function getDeviceValue(nodeID){
    insertData.push(nodeID);
    async.series([
        function(callback) {
            console.log('getDeviceValue : '+nodeID);
            callback();
        },
        function(calllback){
               working1(nodeID, 'A', function(data, err){
                       if (err) console.log(err);
                       else calllback(null, data);
                       });
        },
        function(calllback){
               working1(nodeID, 'B', function(data, err){
                        if (err) console.log(err);
                        else calllback(null, data);
                        });
        },
    ], function(err, results){
        working2();
    });
}
```